# Check for multiple NA columns and return another column in R

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

I have a dataframe that has multiple columns named as "avg_**metric**", "wkday_avg_**metric**", "event_avg_**metric**" and "monthly_avg_**metric**", in which "**metric**" consists of multiple metrics with these calculations (orders, revenue, etc). I have to check for multiple columns if their rows have NAs and replace them with a row from another column. For that, I created a function that does the same verification for the column "metric" I specify. The thing is that I'm getting the same value for the entire new column that I'm creating, which should not be the case.

I added below an example_fixed on what should be the outcome.

Is there an easier way of doing that? Or am I lacking some logic in the function?

Tks.

Edit: I got the errors on my function, but I'm sure there's a better solution to mine. I tried your solutions, but couldn't apply them for my dataframe. I updated the reprex so you can help me better.

```r
library(tidyverse)

(example <- tibble(country = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                   brand = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                   event = c(1:4),
                   month = c(1:4),
                   weekday = c(1:4),
                   avg_visits = c(5028, NA, NA, NA),
                   avg_revenue = c(12345, NA, NA, NA), 
                   wkday_avg_visits = c(1234, 4355, NA, NA),
                   wkday_avg_revenue = c(12345, 54321, NA, NA),
                   event_avg_visits = c(51271, 59212, 98773, NA),
                   event_avg_revenue = c(98764, 56435, 35634, NA),
                   monthly_avg_visits = c(5028, 5263, 6950, 8902),
                   monthly_avg_revenue = c(63457, 34536, 34574, 23426))) %>% 
  print(width = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 13
#>   country brand event month weekday avg_visits avg_revenue wkday_avg_visits
#>   <chr>   <chr> <int> <int>   <int>      <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 A       A         1     1       1       5028       12345             1234
#> 2 B       A         2     2       2         NA          NA             4355
#> 3 C       B         3     3       3         NA          NA               NA
#> 4 D       B         4     4       4         NA          NA               NA
#>   wkday_avg_revenue event_avg_visits event_avg_revenue monthly_avg_visits
#>               <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1             12345            51271             98764               5028
#> 2             54321            59212             56435               5263
#> 3                NA            98773             35634               6950
#> 4                NA               NA                NA               8902
#>   monthly_avg_revenue
#>                 <dbl>
#> 1               63457
#> 2               34536
#> 3               34574
#> 4               23426

subs_metric <- function(data, metric) {
  
  avg <- paste0("avg_", metric)
  wkday_avg <- paste0("wkday_avg_", metric)
  event_avg <- paste0("event_avg_", metric)
  monthly_avg <- paste0("monthly_avg_", metric)
  
  for (i in nrow(data)) {
    
    value <- if (is.na(data[[avg]][i]) & is.na(data[[wkday_avg]][i]) & is.na(data[[event_avg]][i])) {
      data[[monthly_avg]][i]
    } else if (is.na(data[[avg]][i]) & is.na(data[[wkday_avg]][i])) {
      data[[event_avg]][i]
    } else if (is.na(data[[avg]][i])) {
      data[[wkday_avg]][i]
    } else {
      data[[avg]][i]
    }
    
    return(value) 
  }
}
  

example %>% 
  mutate(avg_visits_new = subs_metric(., "visits"),
         avg_revenue_new = subs_metric(., "revenue")) %>% 
  print(width = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 15
#>   country brand event month weekday avg_visits avg_revenue wkday_avg_visits
#>   <chr>   <chr> <int> <int>   <int>      <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 A       A         1     1       1       5028       12345             1234
#> 2 B       A         2     2       2         NA          NA             4355
#> 3 C       B         3     3       3         NA          NA               NA
#> 4 D       B         4     4       4         NA          NA               NA
#>   wkday_avg_revenue event_avg_visits event_avg_revenue monthly_avg_visits
#>               <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1             12345            51271             98764               5028
#> 2             54321            59212             56435               5263
#> 3                NA            98773             35634               6950
#> 4                NA               NA                NA               8902
#>   monthly_avg_revenue avg_visits_new avg_revenue_new
#>                 <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1               63457           8902           23426
#> 2               34536           8902           23426
#> 3               34574           8902           23426
#> 4               23426           8902           23426

(example_fixed <- tibble(country = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                         brand = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                         event = c(1:4),
                         month = c(1:4),
                         weekday = c(1:4),
                         avg_visits = c(5028, NA, NA, NA),
                         avg_revenue = c(12345, NA, NA, NA), 
                         wkday_avg_visits = c(1234, 4355, NA, NA),
                         wkday_avg_revenue = c(12345, 54321, NA, NA),
                         event_avg_visits = c(51271, 59212, 98773, NA),
                         event_avg_revenue = c(98764, 56435, 35634, NA),
                         monthly_avg_visits = c(5028, 5263, 6950, 8902),
                         monthly_avg_revenue = c(63457, 34536, 34574, 23426),
                         avg_visits_new = c(5028, 4355, 98773, 8902),
                         avg_revenue_new = c(12345, 54321, 35634, 23426))) %>% 
  print(width = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 15
#>   country brand event month weekday avg_visits avg_revenue wkday_avg_visits
#>   <chr>   <chr> <int> <int>   <int>      <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 A       A         1     1       1       5028       12345             1234
#> 2 B       A         2     2       2         NA          NA             4355
#> 3 C       B         3     3       3         NA          NA               NA
#> 4 D       B         4     4       4         NA          NA               NA
#>   wkday_avg_revenue event_avg_visits event_avg_revenue monthly_avg_visits
#>               <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1             12345            51271             98764               5028
#> 2             54321            59212             56435               5263
#> 3                NA            98773             35634               6950
#> 4                NA               NA                NA               8902
#>   monthly_avg_revenue avg_visits_new avg_revenue_new
#>                 <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1               63457           5028           12345
#> 2               34536           4355           54321
#> 3               34574          98773           35634
#> 4               23426           8902           23426
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways of doing this, for example you can replace the whole function with:

```
subs_metric <- function(data, metric)
{
  data.table::fcoalesce(data[grep(metric, names(data)), ])
}
```

Which gives the correct result:

```
example %>% 
  mutate(avg_visits_new = subs_metric(., "visits"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   avg_visits wkday_avg_visits event_avg_visits monthly_avg_visits avg_visits_new
#>        <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>              <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1       5028             1234            51271               5028           5028
#> 2         NA             4355            59212               5263           4355
#> 3         NA               NA            98773               6950          98773
#> 4         NA               NA               NA               8902           8902
```

However, I'm sure you would like to know where the flaws in your code were that stopped the loop working as expected.

Firstly, your loop starts with `for (i in nrow(data))`. Since there are 4 rows in your data frame, this means `for (i in 4)`. That means the loop only runs once with `i` set to 4. I think you meant `for (i in 1:nrow(data))`

Secondly, you are returning `value` *inside* the loop. That means that any time the loop runs, it will only run once and the function will return `value`. I think this was just a misplaced curly bracket.

Thirdly, you are overwriting `value` in each iteration of the loop, where you want `value` to be the vector that will form your new column, so you need to declare `value` in advance and write to `value[i]` for each iteration of the loop.

Incorporating these changes, we have:

```r
subs_metric <- function(data, metric) {
  
  avg         <- paste0("avg_", metric)
  wkday_avg   <- paste0("wkday_avg_", metric)
  event_avg   <- paste0("event_avg_", metric)
  monthly_avg <- paste0("monthly_avg_", metric)
  value       <- numeric(nrow(data))
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    
      value[i] <- if (is.na(data[[avg]][i]) & 
                      is.na(data[[wkday_avg]][i]) & 
                      is.na(data[[event_avg]][i])) {
        data[[monthly_avg]][i]
      } else if (is.na(data[[avg]][i]) & 
                 is.na(data[[wkday_avg]][i])) {
        data[[event_avg]][i]
      } else if (is.na(data[[avg]][i])) {
        data[[wkday_avg]][i]
      } else {
        data[[avg]][i]
      }
  }
  return(value) 
}
```

Which now gives the correct result:

```
example %>% 
  mutate(avg_visits_new = subs_metric(., "visits"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   avg_visits wkday_avg_visits event_avg_visits monthly_avg_visits avg_visits_new
#>        <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>              <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1       5028             1234            51271               5028           5028
#> 2         NA             4355            59212               5263           4355
#> 3         NA               NA            98773               6950          98773
#> 4         NA               NA               NA               8902           8902
```

However, I'd probably stick to one of the other solutions offered, since they are considerably shorter and more efficient than a row-wise loop.

Comment: tks for adjusting my function. I updated the example in case it helps to understand my case. I also tried your approach, but it keeps giving me this error: Error: Problem with mutate() input avg_visits_new. x Input avg_visits_new can't be recycled to size 6048. i Input avg_visits_new is test_fun(., "visits"). i Input avg_visits_new must be size 6048 or 1, not 4

Answer (score 2):

We could use the following

```
example$avg_visits_new <- apply(example,1,function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])


# A tibble: 4 x 5
  avg_visits wkday_avg_visits event_avg_visits monthly_avg_visits avg_visits_new
       <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>              <dbl>          <dbl>
1       5028             1234            51271               5028           5028
2         NA             4355            59212               5263           4355
3         NA               NA            98773               6950          98773
4         NA               NA               NA               8902           8902
```

This just goes row-by-row and uses the first non-`NA` value it finds

---

**Edit:**
here is a loop that will add recycle the above code on all the metrics.

```
metric <- unique(sub(".*_(.*)","\\1",colnames(example)[-(1:5)]))

for(i in metric){
    example <- cbind(example, print(apply(example[,grepl(i,colnames(example))],1,function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])))
}

colnames(example)[(ncol(example)-length(metric)+1):ncol(example)] <- paste0("avg_",metric,"_new")



> example

  country brand event month weekday avg_visits avg_revenue wkday_avg_visits wkday_avg_revenue event_avg_visits event_avg_revenue monthly_avg_visits monthly_avg_revenue avg_visits_new avg_revenue_new
1       A     A     1     1       1       5028       12345             1234             12345            51271             98764               5028               63457           5028           12345
2       B     A     2     2       2         NA          NA             4355             54321            59212             56435               5263               34536           4355           54321
3       C     B     3     3       3         NA          NA               NA                NA            98773             35634               6950               34574          98773           35634
4       D     B     4     4       4         NA          NA               NA                NA               NA                NA               8902               23426           8902           23426
```

Comment: Nice solution for the example given in the question Daniel, though I think the OP was looking for a function that could be applied according to the `metric` suffix, as there are many such columns in the actual data frame

Comment: @AllanCameron, you may be right. If OP see's this they should update the example to be representative of the actual dateset.

Comment: That's a nice solution Daniel, tks! Though I have many metrics (9 different metrics to be more precise) and they are kinda messy in the dataframe (as in the example I updated)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a solution. Still in Base-R